# Using require.ensure in webpack

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, require

I am working with angular-webpack and want to use require.ensure() with it.

```
var app=  angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate',
                                      'react',
                                      require('angular-ui-router')
                                ]);

require("./aController.js")(app);
require("./bController.js")(app);
require("./cController.js")(app);
require("./dController.js")(app);
```

say i need `bController` after clicking a button. and i need to load `aController` in the beginning. and i need `cController` and `dController` after `bController`is loaded.

**bController is**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.controller('bController',['$state', function($state) {
        ...
        ...
    }]);
};
```

How will i use `require.ensure` in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this great [tutorial](https://luwenhuang.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/angular-webpack-and-gulp-for-an-spa-part-iii/).

You need to use `require.ensure` in cooperation with [ocLazyLoad](https://luwenhuang.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/angular-webpack-and-gulp-for-an-spa-part-iii/).